# How can i convert .txt to .gpx with an API in web or get GPX export?

Tags: javascript, html, gis, openlayers, openlayers-3

i'm working on a web mapping project with openlayers (a JavaScript API for web GIS) and i need to make a option for users to get .gpx Export from coordinates that they have been before.

I am making an option to export TXT with a JavaScript API.

Is there any API to convert my TXT to GPX?

Is there a different method for exporting GPX files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure that's possible with OpenLayers 3. You dont need to create an TXT first and then convert it to the GPX. In OpenLayers 3 there is a function called [`ol.format.GPX()`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.2.0/apidoc/ol.format.GPX.html) which will convert your features to a gpx format. With `writeFeatures()` you can add you features to the ol gpx object. Here is a working [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6RS2z/604/).

Comment: excuse me .how can i get that in a file with javascript?

Comment: Do you want that the user have the choice to save the fie locally ? Or do you want to save the file on your server ? Pls upvote my answer if it was useful ...

Comment: ok. i wanna do first(locally) an save that on client.if it is possible say me can i save that on server.

Comment: JS is not a language suited for serverside interaction. You can do that with php. Do it with XMLHttpRequest() and $POST oder $GET

Comment: that means i should use XMLHttpRequest()  in client side and use PHP in server side?

Comment: Yes thats a possible approach

Comment: thank u very much for ur help ,it was very useful for me

Comment: i have just 10 REPUTATION and it seems to have at least 15  REPUTATION 
if i get 15 i do that, now there was an error .

Comment: hm now i see you have above 15 :)

Comment: hi 
i have a problem to make a file with .gpx extension. 
i can get gpx code and save it in .txt file but i need to make a file that have .gpx extension .
thank u

Comment: pls ask you question in a new post

Comment: @Manuel is there a way to read GPX file in Flutter?